differentiating the correct use of Use of が vs. を
The biggest thing I'm struggling with japanese right now is the use of particles. I'm following the classic "Minna no Nihongo" book and I'm at Lesson-27, where it says: When potential verbs are used we replace the を by が + ..けます form of the verb: For example:
私は日本語を話します -> 私は日本語が話せます
But, I asked for other sentences to some of my japanese friends and they say in this:
雨が降っていても、この道を歩けます is correct instead of 雨が降っていても、この道が歩けます
I'm really confused how to figure this out. Is there anything that I can use to make sure I'm using the right one or differentiate what particle to use?

Edit: Zorf's answer is better.
There isn't an equivalent grammar in English, so it'll be hard to explain in simple terms. The best and shortest answer can be that you can get used to differentiating them by repetition rather than logical thinking.
Now grammatically speaking,

を is used for actions that are being acted, have been acted, or will be acted. When you 日本語を何々する, you are acting on 日本語. Examples to help with memory construct: 日本語を忘れた。日本語を話す。日本語を使った。
が is used for statements that do not involve an active/activated action. When you 日本語が何々する/日本語が何々です, you are explaining a non-active action.  Examples to help with memory construct: 日本語が話せる。日本語が忘れられる。日本語が好きです。日本語が難しい言語です。

(I am not using the standard terms, just what makes sense in English. so appreciate edits on this)
